# Django Admin: Show different models to different users

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-permissions

I have two superusers (`user1` and `user2`) and two models (`ModelA` and `ModelB`). In the admin page, I want to show just `ModelA` to `user1`, so `user1` can only edit `ModelA` instances but not `ModelB` instances. Similarly, I want to have `user2` able to edit `ModelB` instances only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Superusers can edit everything, but you can give `staff` access to those users and only assign the relevant roles.

Comment: @Selcuk  Can you explain how to assign the relevant roles? Some code would help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `has_change_permission` is for. You can grant edit permission to specific users.

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_change_permission(self, request):
        if request.user.username == 'xyz':
            # Feel free to return false to hide this TestAdmin to xyz user
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

in has_module_permission you can do the following:

```
def has_module_permission(self, request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:  # show for super user anyway
        return True
    if request.user ... complete the condition:
        return True
```

you should have something to differentiate between users, like having more attributes for different users (admin, staff, editors) and so on.

```
if request.user.role = "staff":
    return True
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`user1` and `user2` cannot be superusers if you need to limit their access to `ModelA` and `ModelB` respectively. So, please refactor that first.

Yes, you can give specific users to specific models access in Django admin interface. Please have a look at Django docs: [Permissions and Authorizations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

There is also a good tutorial on setting up permissions and groups at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Let me know if you have confusions after reading along the resources.

Thanks!